# Tensorflow Agent that choose random action

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I want to create agent using tensorflow. I have 9 categories of action: roll, roll left, roll right, brake ... etc. The output from tensorflow pipeline is array[9]. Base on that I will simulate pushing combination of WSAD. Sometimes however I want to choose random action but not completely random but based on dense softmax output. Function that does exactly what I want is numpy.random.multinomial. However tensorflow.random.multinomial returns only index of chosen action not tensor with dimensions same as input. I tried to save actions and feed them later in teach phase to agent however example which I based on would need to feed action during playing phase which I dont want.
I know that this is possible using tensorflow.cond and tesorflow.equal but pipeline will look like mess and Iam not sure about performance. Is other words is there in tensorflow function that behaves like numpy.random.multinomial or there is a reason why  there is none and architecture of my agent is not correct?

Agent itself:

```py
 class agentY():
    def __init__(self,lr,s_size,a_size,h_size):
        self.state_in = tf.placeholder(shape = [None]+list(s_size),dtype=tf.float32)
        conv1         = tf.layers.conv2d(self.state_in,32,4,strides=(4, 4))
        max_pool1     = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1,32,4)
        flatten       = tf.layers.flatten(max_pool1)
        hidden        = tf.layers.dense(flatten,4096,activation=tf.nn.tanh)


        hidden_action       = tf.layers.dense(hidden,2048, activation=tf.nn.elu)
        self.action         = tf.layers.dense(hidden_action,9, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

        self.action_in      = tf.placeholder(shape =[None,9],dtype=tf.float32, name='acin') 
        cross_entropy       = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=self.action_in,
                                                                  logits=self.action)
        optimizer             = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)

        self.gradients = [grad for grad, variable in grads_and_vars]
        self.gradient_placeholders = []
        grads_and_vars_feed = []
        for grad, variable in grads_and_vars:
            gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grad.get_shape())
            self.gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
            grads_and_vars_feed.append((gradient_placeholder, variable))
        self.training_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_feed)
```

Playing phase:

```py
    state = get_state()
    action = sess.run([myAgent.action], feed_dict={myAgent.state_in:[state]}) #
    action = numpy.random.multinomial(1,action[0][0])
    if do_action:
        releaseKeys();
        update_pressed_keys(categoriesToKeys(action))

    reward = reward + delta_time
    current_rewards.append(reward)
    current_gradients.append(myAgent.gradients)
```

Teach phase:

```py
    def teach_agent(agent, all_rewards, all_gradients,sess):
        rewards = np.array(discount_and_normalize_rewards(all_rewards,0.99))
        test = []
        feed_dict = {}
        for var_index, gradient_placeholder in enumerate(agent.gradient_placeholders):
            mean_gradients = np.mean([reward * all_gradients[game_index][step][var_index]
                                      for game_index, rewards in enumerate(all_rewards)
                                          for step, reward in enumerate(rewards)], axis=0)
            feed_dict[gradient_placeholder] = mean_gradients
        sess.run(agent.training_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Teach phase is not yet tested. This code is based on book  "Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to run tensorflow.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2() with labels and logits with shape [None,1] where this tensor is index of action (category). I had a GPU-side crash and realized that I was wrong entire time and forgot about one of the most important function: one-hot encoding. I used multinomial to compute index and than one-hot encoded result. The example below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

p = tf.placeholder(shape = [None,4],dtype=tf.float32)
t = tf.nn.softmax(p)
t1      = tf.random.categorical(tf.log(t),1)
t2 = tf.one_hot(t1, 4,
           on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0,
           axis=-1)


with tf.Session() as sess:
    inArray = [[0.8,0.5,0.1,0.2]]
    index, outArray = sess.run([t1,t2],feed_dict={p:inArray})
    print("Index:",index)
    print("Array:",outArray)
```

This was of course rookie mistake, Iam new to ML and had hard time understading tensor flow.
Now Agent looks like that:

```py
class agentY():
    def __init__(self,lr,s_size,a_size,h_size):
        self.state_in = tf.placeholder(shape = [None]+list(s_size),dtype=tf.float32)
        conv1         = tf.layers.conv2d(self.state_in,32,4,strides=(4, 4))
        max_pool1     = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1,32,4)
        flatten       = tf.layers.flatten(max_pool1)
        hidden        = tf.layers.dense(flatten,4096,activation=tf.nn.tanh)


        hidden_action       = tf.layers.dense(hidden,2048, activation=tf.nn.elu)
        self.action_logits  = tf.layers.dense(hidden_action,9, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
        self.action_out     = tf.one_hot(tf.multinomial(self.action_logits,1), 9,on_value=1.0, off_value=0.0,axis=-1)
        cross_entropy       = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(labels=self.action_out,
                                                                  logits=self.action_logits)
        optimizer             = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
        grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)

        self.gradients = [grad for grad, variable in grads_and_vars]
        self.gradient_placeholders = []
        grads_and_vars_feed = []
        for grad, variable in grads_and_vars:
            gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=grad.get_shape())
            self.gradient_placeholders.append(gradient_placeholder)
            grads_and_vars_feed.append((gradient_placeholder, variable))
        self.training_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars_feed)

tf.reset_default_graph()
testAgent = agentY(0.1,(300,400,1),9,11)
```

The problem now is that Iam harvesting gradients every Agent decision. It take enormous amount of RAM and Iam sure not recomended. Take a look below:

```py
while True:
    time0 = time.time()
    #-----------------zzx
    if collectData:
        state = get_state()
        action_out, gradients = sess.run([myAgent.action_out,myAgent.gradients], feed_dict={myAgent.state_in:[state]})

        if do_action:
            releaseKeys();
            update_pressed_keys(categoriesToKeys(action))

        reward = reward + delta_time
        current_rewards.append(reward)
        current_gradients.append(gradients)
```

I later will use these gradients in function teach_agent() to introduce reward into Agent's network. (teach_agent is posted in original post). Before I return to book and will try to understand next example of Q-Learning Agent could somebody (if this is possible) in easy way explain other way for Q-Learning or Reinforce Learning?